# CSS/JS: Slide down and up transition using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I want to implement a slide down and up transition without using jQuery.
So I tried the following vanilla JS solutions:

https://w3bits.com/javascript-slidetoggle/

https://gist.github.com/ludder/4226288

But those solutions don't work using my HTML structure (a lot of flex boxes).
Here is a simplyfied example. 
https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/eYmOmMX

Use `showElement()` and `hideElement()` to slide down and up the 2nd element. As you will see, the animation don't work correctly.

Using jQuery to realize it, it works fine. But I would like to avoid using jQuery (especially when I use only two jQ functions) and instead implement it with vanilla js.

So is there a working solution with vanilla js to implement a slide down and up animation?

Answer (score 0):

> You can do the slidedown-up using simple css, if you need this in javascript then simple add style to the control onclick

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body { font-family: sans-serif;} 
#content { margin: 50px; } 
a { text-decoration: none; }  
 
.expandable {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;   
  line-height: 50px;

  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
 }
 
 .expandable:target {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"> 
  <a href="#nav"><span>Click Here</span></a>
  <div class="expandable" id="nav" onClick="showdiv(this)">
    <p>Cum enim magna parturient</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#nav2"><span>Click Here</span></a>
  <div class="expandable" id="nav2">
    <p>Cum enim magna parturient</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please have a look at my example: https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/eYmOmMX.  There is no fixed height. Each element has a dynamic height, because it can contain different content (picture, text, numbers, ...).

Comment: you can set dynamic height using document.querySelector(".expandable:target").style.height = "50px"

Comment: For my usecase this is not working. I think I need a slide up and down js animation which is working pretty similar to jQuery's.